# Custom Classes and "Observing" changes with useEffect in React/Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have simplified my issue in a [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-microservice-lkfiq?file=/src/App.tsx:213-292) for ease of a demo. Think of this counter class as a more complex external Lib.

*Explanation*

I have a Class that has a property of a count and method that will increment that count.

```
interface Counter {
  count: number;
  increment(): void;
  autoIncrement(): void;
}

export class MyCounter implements Counter {
  public count: number;

  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
  }

  public increment() {
    this.count = this.count + 1;
    console.log(this.count);
  }
  autoIncrement() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.count = this.count + 1;
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

In a react app I initialise the class and put it in a Memo to prevent unnecessary initialisations of it.

```
  const counter = useMemo(() => {
    return new MyCounter();
  }, []);
```

Then I display the count in my React App along with a button to increment it.

I then "observe" the changes of the button click in a `useEffect` like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("counter", counter.count);
  }, [counter]);
```

but clicking the button and incrementing the count does not update in the React component.

Why is that? In my understanding of Hooks it should work but I might be fundamentally miss understanding what is happening here.

I have tried passing the class instance to a Child component and using it as props, still to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

> ...but clicking the button and incrementing the count does not update in the React component.
>
> Why is that?

Because the value in `counter`, which is a reference to the `Counter` object, didn't change; modifying the `count` property doesn't create a new object. If you want to observe changes to `counter.count`, that's what should be in the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("counter", counter.count);
}, [counter.count]);
//         ^^^^^^
```

(Or you might use `[counter, counter.count]`.)

**But**, if you're using `counter.count` when rendering, it should be in [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) so changes to it cause re-rendering. (And if `counter` is in state, you need to create a new instance each time you increment the counter, because [you can't directly modify state objects](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly).)

Comment: Thank you, That clarifies it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

React js component re-render only if state changed or props changed
here in your case. the counter.count is not a props and not a state so your App.js will not re-render to display the new value of count variable.
I didn't get why you use new class to do that you can simply do it with state.

Comment: I have simplified my issue in a code-sandbox for ease of a demo. Think of this counter class as a more complex external Lib.

Comment: @A.H.Wegemoed so if it's external lib for exemple you can use redux to save your count everyTime you execute the increment the new result must be saved in store and your component must be connected to this store and read the latest value everytime there is a change

Comment: Great thanks, I'll try that. 